# Non parametric equivalent to a mixed ANOVA?

Tags: anova, nonparametric, continuous-data

I have some data from a trial where I have two groups of patients (20 with ongoing disease and 20 without disease).

Both groups have some continuous data at three time points from a subjective outcome measure (on dizziness).

I would like to know whether the resolution of the disease has an effect on the subjective outcome measure. I thought I would need to use a mixed ANOVA, but my continuous data is not normally distributed. Which non-parametric test should I choose instead?

Comment: Generalized linear mixed models extend linear mixed models (which is what I assume a mixed ANOVA is) to non-gaussian responses.

Comment: A little more information would help you get good advice.  1) What do you mean by "my continuous data is not normally distributed"?  How did you determine this, and what do you mean by "data" in this context? It is *very* common for people to have misunderstandings about this model assumption. 2) Can you say a little bit about your dependent variable ?  That will allow someone to suggest an appropriate*generalized* linear model.